# Android bottom navigation issue with DeppLinks and multiple backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-deep-link

I'm implementing an application with bottom naviagtion and multiple backstack using latest android navigation component. My goal is to navigate between tow independent graphs using deeplink.

**App basic structure:**

```
Tab #1: Root -> A -> B -> C
Tab #2: Root -> D -> E
Tab #3: Root -> F -> G (deeplink: https://test.com)

Navigate from C -> G by calling findNavController().navigate(deepLink = Uri.parse("https://test.com"))
```

**Forward navigation:**

The forward navigation goes right, the fragment **G** is presented and the **Tab #3** is selected as current item on the bottom navigation.

**Backwars navigation:**

**Option #1:** Clicking the System back button works fine, the fragment **C** is presented and the **Tab #1** is selected.

**Option #2:** Clicking the **Tab #1** does nothing when it should show the **C** fragment.

**PD: Is there another way we can implement tabs switching without deeplink?**

[Link to example source code](https://github.com/cmpeguerog/android-bottom-navigation)